# convergence rate of law of large number for uniform distribution.

Tags: probability

Assume $x_i, i = 1,2,3... L$ are i.i.d variable of discrete uniform distribution $\left \{ a_1, a_2, ... ,a_k \right \}$.  By LLN, we know: $\frac{1}{L} \sum_i x_i \rightarrow \frac{1}{k}\sum_j a_j  = \bar{a}$

I want to find useful bound on the convergence rate. 
This is where I am so far: 
$$
P \left ( \left | \frac{1}{L} \sum_i x_i - \bar{a} \right | \geq  b \right )
\leq \frac{Var\left ( \frac{1}{L} \sum_i x_i \right )}{b^2} = \frac{ \sum_j (a_j - \bar{a})^2}{Lb^2} 
$$
however, i don't think the bound by chebyshev inequality is very useful. Is there any tighter bound known? 
We can make a the assumption that the variances is bounded by a small constant.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the exponential form of the Chebyshev inequality. For simplicity I will assume that $\bar a =0$.

$P(|{{1} \over {L}}   \sum_i x_i| \geq b)$ = $P(e^{s{| {1\over L}\sum_i x_i | }} \geq e^{sb})\leq e^{-sb} E(e^{s{| {1\over L}\sum_i x_i | }}) $

for all $s>0$, and in concrete cases, you can explicitly compute the right hand side as a function of $s$ to find

$P(|{{1} \over {L}}   \sum_i x_i| \geq b) \leq \min_s e^{-sb} E(e^{s{| {1\over L}\sum_i x_i | }}) $.

Comment: Get rid of the absolute values and use the factorisation $E(\mathrm e^{s(x_1+\cdots+x_L)})=E(\mathrm e^{sx_1})^L$ to make the rate function more explicit.